# Is there a way to build topology and work with topology relations in PyQGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, pyqgis, topology, generalization

Is there a way to build topology and work with topology relations in PyQGIS?

I'm asking because I need to run some custom generalization algorithms on my data, and I need to preserve topology. Presumably this would be easier if there is already some functionality for handling topology in QGIS.

The data is basically shapefiles with multipart-polygons.